# Access an array item in its definition, relative index

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I am trying to define this array:

```
    postLists = [
    [
        [46276,76235,78128],
        postLists[0][0].length,
        1100
    ], [
        [],
        postLists[1][0].length,
        0
    ]
];
```

However, I get an undefined error for all the `postLists[x][0].length` lines.

How do I access the array being defined from itself? Is there a way to relatively select an item without referencing its entire "path" like you would do with folders?
For example in this case, something like `[0].length` would get `[46276,76235,78128]`'s length, or `..[1]` (parent) would select `postLists[1]`.

`postLists[x][0]` will hold hundreds of thousands of integers, so performance need to be considered.
`postLists[x][1]` is the original length which needs to be accessed every few seconds, because of the size of `postLists[x][0]`, it cannot be accessed on the fly so often without harming performance.
`postLists[x][2]` is an index to keep track (and store) the items processed, in `postLists[0][2]` the `1100` is used to skip the 1100 first items which have already been processed.

I am using this in a Greasemonkey script, the reason for the sub-arrays in postLists is that I plan to use the script on multiple tabs running at the same time.

The start of the script is setup like this:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.altKey) {
        switch(event.keyCode) {
            case 49: activeList = postLists[0]; break; // 1
            case 50: activeList = postLists[1]; break; // 2
            case 51: activeList = postLists[2]; break; // 3
            case 52: activeList = postLists[3]; break; // 4

            case 70: // F
                toggleScript = !toggleScript;
                if (toggleScript) {
                    treatItem();
                    favObserver.observe(topNotice, {attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true});
                } else
                    stopObserving(true);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Every functions then use `activeList` to refer the selected sub-array.

Comment: You can't do that in an array literal, since the value hasn't been assigned to *postLists* yet, so *postLists[0]* doesn't exist yet (unless it's been assigned previously).

Comment: This is similar to [other questions about object literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations), though I don't recall seeing one specifically about an array before. Same principle though. (Why do you need the array lengths as separate elements though? Can't you just use `postLists[x][0].length` to get the current length of that array whenever you need it?)

Comment: @an01 why don't you poputale the lengths *after* setting the array?

Comment: P.S. You can do something like this: `postLists  = [
    [
        [46276,76235,78128],
        0,
        1100
    ], [
        [],
        0,
        0
    ]
].map(v => { v[1]=v[0].length; return v });`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado For various reasons in my program, I need the length item to be in second. The array will handle up to hundreds of thousands of variables, so I'd rather avoid using something like splice() which would probably be a huge slowdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize assignment, with side-effect of creating additional variable; e.g.,  `tmp`, used to assign, re-assign a variable which can change multiple occassions

```js
var tmp, postLists = [
  [
    tmp = [46276, 76235, 78128],
    tmp.length,
    1100
  ],
  [
    tmp = [],
    tmp.length,
    0
  ]
];
delete tmp;
console.log(postLists);
```

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, you are correct. See updated post, adjusted approach to use single variable which changes, or can be changed multiple occasions

Comment: Yep, saw that. +1 on the edited version. (You could also declare `var tmp, postLists = ...` to avoid a global.)